# asPOSIXct returns NA in only 1 out of 2000 rows

Tags: r, posixct

I have a dataframe with geolocator observations and corresponding timestamps. I add a subset of the dataframe below:

```
DET <- structure(list(id = c(200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 
200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 
200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 
200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 
200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1), 
    date = c("2021-03-03 02:00:00", "2021-03-03 14:00:00", "2021-03-04 02:00:00", 
    "2021-03-04 14:00:00", "2021-03-05 02:00:00", "2021-03-05 14:00:00", 
    "2021-03-06 02:00:00", "2021-03-06 14:00:00", "2021-03-07 02:00:00", 
    "2021-03-07 14:00:00", "2021-03-08 02:00:00", "2021-03-08 14:00:00", 
    "2021-03-09 02:00:00", "2021-03-09 14:00:00", "2021-03-10 02:00:00", 
    "2021-03-10 14:00:00", "2021-03-11 02:00:00", "2021-03-11 14:00:00", 
    "2021-03-12 02:00:00", "2021-03-12 14:00:00", "2021-03-13 02:00:00", 
    "2021-03-13 14:00:00", "2021-03-14 02:00:00", "2021-03-14 14:00:00", 
    "2021-03-15 02:00:00", "2021-03-15 14:00:00", "2021-03-16 02:00:00", 
    "2021-03-16 14:00:00", "2021-03-17 02:00:00", "2021-03-17 14:00:00", 
    "2021-03-18 02:00:00")), row.names = 1330:1360, class = "data.frame")
```

I then try to convert the column "date" from a character to a POSIXct format:

```
DET$date <- as.POSIXct(DET$date,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="US/Eastern")
```

This works fine but for one single row, i.e. row 1352, that returns an NA.

```
issue <- structure(list(id = c(200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 
200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 
200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 
200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 
200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1, 200368.1), 
    date = structure(c(1614754800, 1614798000, 1614841200, 1614884400, 
    1614927600, 1614970800, 1615014000, 1615057200, 1615100400, 
    1615143600, 1615186800, 1615230000, 1615273200, 1615316400, 
    1615359600, 1615402800, 1615446000, 1615489200, 1615532400, 
    1615575600, 1615618800, 1615662000, NA, 1615744800, 1615788000, 
    1615831200, 1615874400, 1615917600, 1615960800, 1616004000, 
    1616047200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "US/Eastern")), row.names = 1330:1360, class = "data.frame")
```

I have not found an answer yet, why this particular row is turned into NA when all other rows are converted to POSIXct just fine. All rows have the same format originally (see example below).

```
> check
           id                date
1350 200368.1 2021-03-13 02:00:00
1351 200368.1 2021-03-13 14:00:00
1352 200368.1 2021-03-14 02:00:00
1353 200368.1 2021-03-14 14:00:00
1354 200368.1 2021-03-15 02:00:00
1355 200368.1 2021-03-15 14:00:00
```

Here are my session infos:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19043)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] purrr_0.3.4          data.table_1.14.2    terra_1.6-17        
 [4] raster_3.6-3         beepr_1.3            dBBMMhomeRange_0.0.9
 [7] tidylog_1.0.2        dplyr_1.0.10         sp_1.5-0            
[10] lubridate_1.8.0      magrittr_2.0.3       remotes_2.4.2       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.9          lattice_0.20-45     tidyr_1.2.1        
 [4] prettyunits_1.1.1   png_0.1-7           class_7.3-20       
 [7] ps_1.7.1            clisymbols_1.2.0    assertthat_0.2.1   
[10] rprojroot_2.0.3     utf8_1.2.2          R6_2.5.1           
[13] plyr_1.8.7          e1071_1.7-11        httr_1.4.4         
[16] ggplot2_3.3.6       pillar_1.8.1        RgoogleMaps_1.4.5.3
[19] rlang_1.0.6         curl_4.3.2          rstudioapi_0.14    
[22] geosphere_1.5-14    callr_3.7.2         rgdal_1.5-32       
[25] stringr_1.4.1       munsell_0.5.0       proxy_0.4-27       
[28] compiler_4.2.1      pkgconfig_2.0.3     pkgbuild_1.3.1     
[31] tidyselect_1.1.2    tibble_3.1.8        codetools_0.2-18   
[34] audio_0.1-10        fansi_1.0.3         crayon_1.5.1       
[37] withr_2.5.0         sf_1.0-8            bitops_1.0-7       
[40] grid_4.2.1          lwgeom_0.2-8        gtable_0.3.1       
[43] lifecycle_1.0.2     DBI_1.1.3           units_0.8-0        
[46] scales_1.2.1        KernSmooth_2.23-20  cli_3.4.1          
[49] stringi_1.7.8       cachem_1.0.6        xml2_1.3.3         
[52] ellipsis_0.3.2      generics_0.1.3      vctrs_0.4.1        
[55] move_4.1.8          rjson_0.2.21        tools_4.2.1        
[58] ggmap_3.0.0         glue_1.6.2          jpeg_0.1-9         
[61] abind_1.4-5         fastmap_1.1.0       processx_3.7.0     
[64] parallel_4.2.1      starsExtra_0.2.7    colorspace_2.0-3   
[67] stars_0.5-6         classInt_0.4-7      memoise_2.0.1
```

Comment: This issue usually results from daylight saving time. Some datetimes simply don't exist because of the switch to DST. You might want to use a time zone without DST if your data-generating process didn't switch to DST (e.g., that's often the case with automatic data loggers).

Comment: `as.POSIXct(DET$date, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="US/Eastern")` works fine for me. You should add `sessionInfo()` as [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73850518/edit).

Comment: @Roland the issue seems to be exactly what you pointed out. If I define a `tz` without daylight savings there are no more NAs. The original data from the loggers is in UTC but I had to convert them to EST with daylight savings due to where the animals were tagged/moved around. If I use `tz="Etc/GMT+5"` there are no more NAs. Thank you!

Comment: @jay.sf I edited my question so it contains the session info now.

Comment: Maybe an issue with the [locale](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/locales.html), although your settings seem to be correct.